# Pure ASP Upload script with additional features

Tags: html, asp-classic

Source: http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/pure-asp-upload-script-with-additional-features-94647.html

Hi again everyone,

Im trying to use "Shadow Wizards" Image upload script that can found above...it works great for me except one thing. One section of my form includes checkboxes with the same name (A list of diseases/foods) I need to be able to select multiples of these to insert into the database but it seems with this running I can only get one of the values to submit (the last value clicked).

I've had a quick look on google and I think i've put it down to being because the enctype on the form is "multipart/form-data".

Does anybody (or even Shadow_Wizard himself) know a way round this? If not im going to have to look into another solution for image upload that will allow multiple checkboxes.

Comment: Why didn't you post a reply in the original thread? I didn't notice this until now, but glad you got excellent help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in that Shadowuploader.asp in lines 159-160. there the strElementValue is overwritten in the m_Reuqest Dictionary.

so you have to do it slightly different:

```
            'append to request collection
        if m_Request.Exists(strElementName) then
            m_Request(strElementName) = m_Request(strElementName) & ", " & strElementValue
        else
            m_Request(strElementName) = strElementValue
        end if
```

so you have comma seperated values if strElementName already exists in m_Request Dictionary.

If you want you could add some extra intelligence and alter every comma seperated value in the m_request dictionary into an array after the Loop:

```
        dim itm, arr, n
    for each itm in m_Request
        if instr(m_Request(itm), ", ") > 0 then
            arr = split( m_Request(itm), ", ")
            m_Request(itm) = arr
        end if
    next
```

after uploading you could access the values of checkboxes like this:

```
objUpload("chk")(1)
```

as always there is no simple solution when using classic asp...

Comment: thank you for your insight...After many hours of thinking, and discussing with fellow students the alternative I came up with (although possible a little messy) is that when the checkbox is select it writes the value (with a "-" before it) (using java) into a hidden text field. that text field is then submitted to the upload page. The solution seems to work for what I need. I appreciate you taking your time to look at this for me however